# Is this the new way of spam? How can i protect my website?

Tags: asp.net, security, spam-prevention

Recently with the Google webmaster tools, i discovered the following (not found) Crawl errors

```
http://mydomain.com/warning_this_is_english_domain_to_solve_this_problem_submit_site_in_atoall.com.html
```

After Googling i found that this one might be a new way of spam.

But wait a second, from programmer's prespecive, what is going on with my website? Is there something am i doing wrong? Is there any security hole i currently do not see?

UPDATE: References

http://blog.colnect.com/2009/12/new-spam-technique-warningthisisenglish.html

http://blog.colnect.com/2009/12/save-us-from-index-spamming.html

Comment: Do you have the reference to the pages you googled?

Comment: Updated the references as requested

Comment: I think they're trying to convince you to visit their URL. Ignore it and ban the originating IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that these people wrote a custom 404 handler that looks nice to humans,  but it also allows hackers to trick bots.  This is a vulnerability that is being actively exploited to spread spam.

If you search for the text,  a ton of these spammer links pop up:
http://www.google.com/search?q=warning+this+is+english+domain+to+save+this+problem&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

The 2nd link for me is this:
http://www.acronymfinder.com/warning_this_is_english_domain_to_solve_this_problem_submit_site_in_atoall.com.html

If you go to the page you'll see the text:
"No matches for warning-this-is-english-domain-to-solve-this-problem-submit-site-in-atoall.com"

To protect your self try the same hack on your system.  Try putting:
http://www.whatever.com/some-bs-text.html

If you can see some-bs-text in your web browser,  then someone oculd trick Google into seeing arbitrary text on your page.  Its better to just tell people that the page cannot be found.

Answer (score 2):

I think this just means that someone (or more likely something) requested that file from your server.  Your server replied with a 404 error, (or possibly a 200) but the error showed up in your log.  This does not indicate any security vulnerability and there is no need for you to take an action.

Comment: I am 100% cretin that this is in fact a vulnerability that is being exploited.  Have a peek at my milw0rm page: http://milw0rm.com/author/677 .  How many exploits have you written?  Stay away from security tags.

Comment: Duly noted, but the exploit does not involve the poster's site being compromised.

Comment: This exploit does require that the site is vulnerable to an attack.  The vast majority of vulnerabilities tracked by the CVE system DO NOT lead to remote code execution.